# IOS Eureka cell color issues

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Could anybody explain what is wrong with the code and the result? It seems despite cellSetup with yellow background color and red text color the cell is formatted strangely (with kind of white rectangle on top of the cell - see attached picture link below).

```
        +++ Section("OCCURRENCE DETAILS")
        <<< TextAreaRow("occ_description") {
            $0.title = ""
            $0.value = "15454646"
            $0.textAreaHeight = .dynamic(initialTextViewHeight: 100)
            }.cellSetup { cell, row in cell.backgroundColor = .yellow; cell.tintColor = .red
            }.onChange { self.occ_description =  $0.value }
```

[Attached Picture: Erroneous Cell Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD9r8.png)

Answer (score 1):

The "white rectangle" is the actual `UITextView` which by default has a white background. To render the entire cell yellow you have to also set the text view's background color to yellow or transparent. Add this to your `cellSetup`:

```
cell.textView.backgroundColor = .clear
```